# Cannot add property key, object is not extensible error Apollo Client with antd

Tags: reactjs, antd, apollo-client

I get an error `Cannot add property key, object is not extensible` using `"@apollo/client": "^3.0.2"` with ant design.

I can successfully obtain data from the server with my graphql query, however, the problem is that, the data inside the return object is somehow unextendable. This never used to be a problem prior to using apollo client (using apollo boost).

In order to make my data work in a table in ant design, I have to pass in the array data obtained from the `data` object returned from the server. The part where I get the error is when I attempt to iterate through the `items` array, and add a `key` to each object, so that react won't complain in the console of a missing `key` element for the html.

```
  const items = [...data.items];
  console.log("items:", items);

  // Add a key for each item to make React stop complaining
  // Erorr occurs here!!!
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.key = item.id;
  });
```

Is there a way we can remove this unnecessary functionality that's hindering our ability in modifying and extending results obtained from the server? Also I tried spreading the array making a deep copy, but that's not working either.

What do I need to do to make sure that I can add an additional `key` field in each array item, based on the `id`?

Addendum:

I don't actually need the code that does the `items.forEach()` stuff. However, if I don't add it, react will complain that the entries in the table are all missing a `key` value. This is my workaround since tables in ant design get their data from an array of objects, and thus, need to have a `key` value in there. Since querying data from the server typically doesn't include a `key` property in an object, this has to be manually added.

Comment: Can you show the way you render those items?

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz   <Table
            dataSource={items} /> It renders properly but if you open up the console, you get react complaining that each row in the table has no `key`, where it obtains the key from each array object's `key` value (which is what Im trying to set, but it won't let me since the object isn't extensible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to figure it out by deep copying the array data, via lodash.

Use `_.cloneDeep()` on the returned `data`'s object that is the name of the object/table you are querying for.

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
import { Table } from "antd";

function Component({ id, query }) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query, {
    variables: { id }
  });

  if (loading) return <div />;
  if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

  const items = _.cloneDeep(data.items);
  console.log("items:", items);

  // Add a key for each item to make React stop complaining
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.key = item.id;
  });

  return (
          <Table
            dataSource={items}
          />
  );
```